# Lattices of minimal covolume in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, lattices, arithmetic-groups

What are the (uniform/non-uniform) irreducible lattices of minimal (or even small) covolume in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Context: Such a lattice will be an order in a quaternion algebra over a totally real number field that (the algebra) splits at precisely two infinite places. Its covolume can be computed from number theoretic data [[Prasad](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1989__69__91_0)]. For the groups $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ people have worked out the lattices of minimal covolume explicitly. Is there something similar for $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Some info here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06443